# How to get trainable variables of keras model in eager execution mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, tensor

I'm using tensorflow 1.15.0.

I build my own model with `tf.keras`. But when I trying to save my model with `Saver`:

```
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
```

I find that `tf.trainable_variables()` will always return empty list in `eager execution mode`.

Here is a simple code sample:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def create_model():
    inlayer = keras.Input(shape=(10), name="input")
    outlayer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inlayer)
    
    model = keras.Model(
        inputs=inlayer,
        outputs=outlayer,
    )
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)
           
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss='mae') 
    return model

model = create_model()

history = model.fit(np.zeros((1, 10)), np.zeros((1, 10)), epochs=1)

tf.trainable_variables()
```

Output is `[]`.

Could someone please tell me why this happens and how could I get trainable_variables for a keras model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `model.trainable_variables`.